# Not able to route in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am not getting how to link different pages in react js. I'm using react router through which by using link and route tags I'm able to change the url but not getting the content. 
Can I get the answer as soon as possible..

Comment: If you are able to change content but not showing the result, you probably don't have a problem with linking but with routing setup please provide some code, so we can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your code snippet?

There might be several reasons, maybe check the router nested settings, and see if it setup correct.